# Consumers kicked out of group - remaining consumers do not pick up unassigned partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We've faced somewhat of a weird situation over the weekend:

A few replicas of our Consumer application failed with following error message:

```
ConsumingMessageError=Offset commit cannot be completed since the consumer is not part of an active group for auto partition assignment; it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group.
```

The reasons for this are not in question, they have been discussed in length in other threads. However, the behaviour of the remaining consumers was unexpected: there were several partitions with 0 lag, as the consumers continued to poll - a bunch of the partitions had a high consumer lag though. My expectation would have been the "lost" partitions to be assigned to the remaining consumers by the group coordinator, as per documentation, but it seems it did not happen. We had to redeploy the broken consumers which fixed the issue in short time.

The consumers do *not* have manually assigned partitions, they subscribe to the Kafka topic with a `ConsumerRebalanceListener`. Whenever our consumers are assigned a new partition, they seek to a specific offset to start from (if desired offset position for given partition is higher than current offset position for that consumer group - otherwise continue at current position). By this we control the starting point per partition once during initial deployment, but do not skip any records for following in-place deployments:

```
public class SeekOffsetsOnAssigned implements ConsumerRebalanceListener {
    private Consumer<?,?> consumer;
    private Map<Integer, Long> offsetsPerPartitionID;

    public SeekOffsetsOnAssigned(Consumer<?,?> consumer, Map<Integer, Long> offsetsToStartFrom) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
        this.offsetsPerPartitionID = offsetsToStartFrom;
    }

    
    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        for(TopicPartition partition: partitions)
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, Long> entry : offsetsPerPartitionID.entrySet()) {
                if ((entry.getKey() == partition.partition()) && consumer.position(partition) < entry.getValue()) {
                       consumer.seek(partition, entry.getValue());
                }
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
}
```

Basically the code in `onPartitionsAssigned()` would surely be without effect in that scenario, however I'm not sure if a specific action would be required in `onPartitionsRevoked()` to trigger the default behaviour of the group coordinator. Does anyone have a clue on how we can avoid this in the future, are we missing something here?

Comment: Have you checked the session.timeout.ms parameter? When consumer is loosing partitions immedietally then partitions will be blocked for time set by that parameter.

Comment: How exactly does this work, do "blocked" partitions simply get assigned after that time expired or is any action required? The `session.timeout.ms parameter was set to 30000ms, but the partitions were (seemingly) unassigned for multiple days.

Comment: Yes partitions will be assigned after that time, it partitions were unassigned for few days it is weird. Have you checked assignement by kafka-consumer-groups script? Maybe partitions are handled by some zombie consumers which are assigned